# OpenStreet Map - Download power data for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, export, download

I want to find power data of OSM. After search I found this source: https://download.osmdata.xyz/

It gives the power data of all the world (6GB file, hard to edit). Is there any other source to download only power data per country (Greece specifically) or at least per continent?

Comment: https://download.geofabrik.de/ here you can download just for a specific country (Greece for your occasion)